# How do I call a web service that uses a command line interface in python?

Tags: python, web-services, command-line-interface

I have experience in calling a REST web service in python but a recent project had me confused.

Here is an example of how to call the webservice :
https://www.winquote.net/cgi-bin/compete.pl?dc=-cv1.5 -ccca -qt0 -pcYOUR_WQ_ACCOUNT -cedv1.0.16.10.11 -rt0 -g1 -alan35:35 -rR -fa500000 -pg0 -pi4 -lc13 -pm0 -rop0  -fmt -ofxml -esxml -skiplegend -langen

Entering this in a browser while replacing "pcYOUR_WQ_ACCOUNT" with my credentials works and returns a list of products. But how would I go about actually implementing this in a python script?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Since you already know how to use Python's REST interface, please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.